# Open new Window in NW.js without menubar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nwjs

Hi I have an app using NW.JS and angularjs. But the problem is, I want to open a new window (that loads a new page from within the app) without inheriting the menubar from the main window's menu. Is this possible in nwjs? Also every time I click the menu item from main window menubar that triggers the opening of new window it always open new window. How can I prevent this? I mean, when I already open the new window, the app should refrain from opening it again unless it was already closed.

in my index.html

```
var menu = new nw.Menu({ type: 'menubar' });

var submenu = new nw.Menu();
submenu.append(new nw.MenuItem({
    label: 'Exit',
    click: function(){
        nw.App.quit();
    }
}));

menu.append(new nw.MenuItem({
    label: 'File',
    submenu: submenu
}));
menu.append(new nw.MenuItem({
    label: 'New Page',
    click: function(){
        nw.Window.open('index.html#/new_page')
    }
}));

nw.Window.get().menu = menu;
```

Comment: I'm working with an older version of nwjs, but I think you have options on creating the window. focus, toolbar and frame, you can set them to false.

Comment: I tried that but toolbar is already deprecated.

Comment: in which OS you are having this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening new window you are using same html file which contains code to create menu bar, so it is obviously going to create menu bar for popup window also, you need to use different html file for popup window.

Below is the full version of code, let me know if it is not working for you

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <title>Demo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //var win = nw.Window.get();
        //win.showDevTools();

        var menu = new nw.Menu({ type: 'menubar' });

        var submenu = new nw.Menu();
        submenu.append(new nw.MenuItem({
            label: 'Exit',
            click: function(){
                nw.App.quit();
            }
        }));

        menu.append(new nw.MenuItem({
            label: 'File',
            submenu: submenu
        }));
        menu.append(new nw.MenuItem({
            label: 'New Page',
            click: function(){
                console.log('open new page');
                var parentWin = window;

                if(parentWin.localStorage.getItem('child_open')) {
                    console.log('child window is already open');
                    return;
                }

                nw.Window.open('home.html#new_page', {}, function(win) {
                    parentWin.localStorage.setItem('child_open', true);

                    win.on('closed', function() {
                        parentWin.localStorage.removeItem('child_open');
                    });
                });
            }
        }));

        nw.Window.get().menu = menu;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <title>Inner Window</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <p id="new_page"> New page section </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This one is okay. But it didn't solve my second issue about new window. Let say for example the user click "New Page" menu, and the home.html is loaded. But whenever the user click again the new page menu it will open a new window. So meaning it can have a virtually infinite new window of the same home.html as long as the user click the menu. How can i prevent this? So if the home.html is loaded, even the user will click the new page menu it will never open new window unless the home.html is still not open.

Comment: or is there any workaround for this? like in 1 window (main) it can have a child window inside of it? i mean the child should not be created in a separate window, it will just be loaded along side with the main window?

Comment: @sse I have updated index.html, please check if it solves your problem

Comment: I will try this later and I will inform you